# When make site responsive i want some my text to disappear! HELP PLS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

So i want my text do disappear like  on page inox-jukic.com when it is in size for mobile text from slider disappear. I got slider too.

Here is css:

```
     /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
     .numbertext {
        color: deepskyblue;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 45px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        font-size-adjust: 0.58;
```

Here is HTML:

```
     <div class="mySlides fade " >
        <div class="numbertext">TITLE <br> TITLE2</div>
        <img src="uploads/building/1_auto_x2.jpg" style="width:100%; ">
        <div class="text">Aluminijske ograd</div>
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides " >
        <div class="numbertext">TITLE<br> TITLE2 </div>
        <img src="uploads/building/2_auto_x2%20(1).jpg" style="width:100%; ">
        <div class="text"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides fade " >
        <div class="numbertext">TITLE</div>
        <img src="uploads/building/3_auto_x2.jpg" style="width:100%; height=400px">
        <div class="text"></div>
     </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Breakpoints inside your CSS File. So if the screensize gets smaller, you can just set the containers to visibility : hidden or display:none. As you want.

Here some typical breakpoints:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

Comment: Please add relevant code inside the answer, [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)